# Office Addin Installation help!

Tags: ms-office

I created a VSTO Excel 2003 addin and a setup project. It works perfect in Excel 2003 and Excel 2007.

When I install the addin in Office 2000. I getting the following error...

> "The Common Language runtime could not
>   be loaded... contact
>   your administrator"

No exception Sad

Since for Office 2000 we need to use the PIA of office 2000. I created the Office 2000 PIA manually and included it in the project and build the project.

The same setup file(office 2000 pia) is working fine in office 2003/2007.

I made the copy local property to true...

Could you please help me what I am missing on this... why it is not working in office 2000...

Answer (score 0):

The only suggestion I can make is to go to the msdn forums...

[social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/)